# pthreads mutex number and performance

Tags: pthreads, mutex

- how many pthreads mutex are usually
  available in a typical system?
- Is having many pthreads mutex   degrades performance?

Comment: You mean does having many blocked threads on mutex degrades performance?

Comment: @Cipi no, I mean having many mutex regardless of status

Answer (score 3):

POSIX allows mutexes to be implemented as a system-level resource, but such an implementation would be considered extremely poor quality and I can't imagine anyone using it. In reality, on modern implementations (think Linux), the number of mutexes you can have is limited only by the virtual address space. (Actually you can have even more, up to the total size of physical memory/swap plus filesystem size, if you use `mmap` and `munmap` to map them in and out as needed.)

As for performance, on 32-bit glibc systems, unlocking robust mutexes is an `O(n)` operation, where `n` is the number of robust mutexes currently locked. This is due to using a singly-linked list where a doubly-linked one is needed; they ran out of space in their `pthread_mutex_t` structure to fit both pointers. This issue only applies for *robust* mutexes, which are rarely used in practice, and only on 32-bit Linux/glibc. For all other mutex types, the number of mutexes has *no impact* on performance. The number of currently-contended-for mutexes, however, does have some impact on performance, but it's a complicated subject beyond the scope of a simple answer.

Answer (score 1):

Several answers:

1. You are asking the wrong question.
   If you need more than a 1000 or so
   mutexes, you are likely doing something
   wrong.
2. As many as you need.
   Non-process-shared mutex does not
   usually consume any resources except
   RAM.
3. Having many unused mutexes degrades performance in exactly the same way as having many integers; that is, not at all (assuming sufficient RAM).

Comment: I disagree. I would say it the other way around: If you only need one mutex, you're probably doing something wrong, like locking code rather than data. It would be very reasonable when doing object-oriented programming for *each object* to contain one or more mutexes.

Comment: On Linux, an ordinary mutex costs exactly 24 bytes. This is not overly burdensome for many use cases.

Comment: @bdonlan You are quite incorrect. On Linux/i386, with glibc, a mutex does indeed cost 24 bytes. On Linux/x86_64 with glibc it costs 40. It is easy to imagine that it costs something other than 40 and 24 bytes on Linux for a different processor, or when using something other than glibc. Also, initializing the mutex *could* be quite expensive (especially if you've got 10,000 of them). Besides, the OP never said he is using Linux to begin with.

Comment: Good point :) It's still pretty cheap on Linux though, relatively speaking - I wouldn't worry too much about it until benchmarks show problems. Worry about getting the locking _right_ first, _then_ fast. And if you're getting the locking right, well, more fine-grained tends to be faster than coarse anyway.